# Sending file via netcat

Tags: linux, netcat

I'm using something like this to send file from one computer to another:

To serve file (on computer A):

```
cat something.zip | nc -l -p 1234
```

To receive file (on computer B):

```
netcat server.ip.here. 1234 > something.zip
```

My question is... can I do the opposite? Let's say I have file on computer B and I want to send it to A but not the way I wrote above, but by making computer that's supposed to receive file (A) be 'listening' server and connect computer that's 'sending' file (B) to server and send the file? Is it possible? I think it might be but I'm not sure how to do this.

**In case my above explanation is messed up: How do I send file TO 'server' instead of serving the file on server and then taking it FROM it (like I did above)?**

Comment: Note: if you're using `nc` because `scp` is too slow and you don't need encryption, you may want to switch to `udpcast`: https://superuser.com/questions/692294/why-is-udcast-is-many-times-faster-than-netcat

Answer (score 78, accepted):

On your server (A):

```
nc -l -p 1234 -q 1 > something.zip < /dev/null
```

On your "sender client" (B):

```
cat something.zip | netcat server.ip.here 1234
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that I'll have to switch sides somehow but I wasn't sure how :). Thanks, it works!

Comment: That's a cute netcat trick.

Comment: why the `< /dev/null` part?

Comment: Because netcat both reads stdin and writes stdout simultaneously, sending anything read from stdin out to the network and printing anything received from the network on stdout. The </dev/null ensures that, when the received file has completed, netcat doesn't sit there indefinitely waiting for input from the console (which it shouldn't be reading anyway!) and also ensures that it doesn't gobble up any input that may be available from the terminal, such as you typing the next command you wanted to run.

Comment: With `-q 1`, I received only a 20-50% of a 1.2GB file.  It worked fine with a higher `-q` value.

Comment: `-q seconds :: after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever`. For me, a `-q` value of `-1` worked for a multi-gig file.

Comment: if you have `pv`, I would suggest operating the "server client" as `pv soemthing.zip | ...`, that will display the progress of the file read going into the pipe.

Comment: With me and -q 0 it works OK for large files.  Maybe it's a bug that was fixed?

Comment: The transmitting side (B) also needs -q0, otherwise it would hang forever

Answer (score 9):

As a note, if you want to also preserve file permissions, ownership and timestamps, we use **tar** with **netcat** to do transfers of directories and files.

On receiving system:

```
nc -l -p 12345 -q 1 | tar xz -C /path/to/root/of/tree
```

From sending system:

```
tar czf - ./directory_tree_to_xfer | nc <host name or IP address of receiving system> 12345
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good addition to the answer, but please leave it as a comment and not as a separate answer.

Comment: Couldn't add a comment above due to lack of Rep points on this sub-board, so I had to offer it as an answer, though apparently, you are allowed to comment on your own answers.

Comment: Doesn't work on MacOS receiver. -q and -l cause errors.

Comment: Tried it without -q and -p (used -l 12345) and is seemed to work on the receiving end. Debian sending end failed abysmally with `Connection timed out
tar: -: Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 141
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

I know the connection is fine though because I'm ssh'd into it right now. Something is wrong with this "answer". I guess this is the part where I spend 2 hours trying nonworking SE answers in order to avoid the 1 hour it would take to copy the file over the network with sftp...

Answer (score 7):

Computer A:  `nc -l -p 1234 > filename.txt`

Computer B:  `nc server.com 1234 < filename.txt`

Should work too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Init the target listening to the port. AKA receiver end

`nc -vl 44444 > pick_desired_name_for_received_file`

Send the file to the target. AKA sender end

`nc -n TargetIP 44444 < /path/to/file/you/want/to/send`

read more
https://www.maketecheasier.com/netcat-transfer-files-between-linux-computers/
https://gist.github.com/A1vinSmith/78786df7899a840ec43c5ddecb6a4740

Answer (score 1):

I cooked everything for you. Keep it handy for regular use case.
Make sure you change IP and port in this script.

**There are 3 modes.**
*1. direct file transfer

2. compressed file transfer

3. folder transfer*

```
receivefile() {
    [ $# -lt 1 ] && echo '$0 <file> <port>' && return 1
    local file=$1
    local port=${18080:-2}
    md5sum $file
    nc -v -l 0.0.0.0 -p $port > $file
}

sendfile() {
    [ $# -lt 1 ] && echo '$0 <file> <server> <port>' && return 1
    local file=$1
    local server=${115.98.2.1:-2}
    local port=${18080:-3}
    md5sum $file
    nc -c $server $port < $file
}

receivefilecompressed() {
    [ $# -lt 1 ] && echo '$0 <file> <port>' && return 1
    local file=$1
    local port=${18080:-2}
    md5sum $file
    nc -v -l 0.0.0.0 -p $port | gunzip > $file
}

sendfilecompressed() {
    [ $# -lt 1 ] && echo '$0 <file> <server> <port>' && return 1
    local file=$1
    local server=${115.98.2.1:-2}
    local port=${18080:-3}
    md5sum $file
    gzip -c $file | nc -c $server $port
}

receivefolder() {
    local port=${18080:-1}
    nc -v -l 0.0.0.0 -p $port | tar zxv
}

sendfolder() {
    [ $# -lt 1 ] && echo '$0 <folder> <server> <port>' && return 1
    local folder=$1
    local server=${115.98.2.1:-2}
    local port=${18080:-3}
    tar czp $folder | nc -c $server $port
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start another instance of netcat on computer B.  Just do what you did on computer A, but serve it from B.  Give the new server a new port.

Comment: I don't want to do the same, I want to change commands to something else (i'm not sure if it's possible)... look at bold text in my question. What I mean is that I don't want to serve from B. I want A to be server listening for input... and then I want to send file contents from non-listening B to listening A.

Comment: That's not how netcat works.

Comment: As you can see from accepted answer - yes, that's how netcat can work too.

Comment: You're right.  I learn something new every day!