# How can I efficiently transfer a large file using a smaller external disk?

Tags: linux, ssd, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, data-transfer

I need to transfer a large (multi-terabyte) file from one Linux computer to another. I have a 1TB external SSD drive that seems like it's the fastest way in terms of bandwidth. My best guess right now is to use `split` to split up the big file into 2-3 smaller chunks and then copy those chunks individually. But this will use up a few extra TB on both the source and destination computers, which is a problem.

Is there a more space or time efficient way to transfer a large file from one computer to another using an external drive?

Comment: If both computers are on the same network, I would seriously consider transferring it via the LAN... it'll be a lot less hassle. If I have to wait 1 hour for an answer like this, it's already too much for me. With a 30mbps connection I could transfer 10G in about 45 minutes!

Comment: If you go on the networking style, I found [this][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/a/98323/342477

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about dd:

```
srchost:$ dd if=/sourcefile of=/dev/ssd1 bs=1G count=1000 skip=[0,1000,...]
```

move disk...

```
dsthost:$ dd if=/dev/ssd1 bs=1G >> /finalfile
```